# Moving a Typescript definition (or declaration) to an "already existing" file with automatic update of references and imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

It is possible to move a definition to a "NEW FILE" by selecting the "Move to a new file" option as shown below in the image, and have the references and imports automatically updated by the Visual Studio Code.

[image]

However, is it possible to move (or append) that definition into an already existing file with the automatic updating of references or imports etc. using any commands or shortcuts?

If not possible directly, are there any other tools or extensions to manage or organize the local relative imports and automatically fix the import paths across the whole project (and/or all referenced projects) after definitions have have been manually moved to a different existing file?